# scanf always prints entered number

Tags: c, scanf

Just started learning C and I have a problem with the scanf function. Every time I enter a number in the console, it will be printed right under the input. The program still works, but it is a little bit annoying.
(I am using CLion from JetBrains)

```
int main()
{
   int x;
   printf("Number: ");
   scanf("%d", &x);
   printf("Your number is %d!", x);
}
```

This is the output:

`Number:15
 15
Your number is 15!
Process finished with exit code 0`

Comment: The code itself does not evoke such behavior. What environment are you using?

Comment: I am using CLion from JetBrains.

Comment: "*`scanf` always prints entered number*" - No, `scanf` doesn't print anything. I am not familiar with JetBrains, but where you enter the number and press `"Enter"` your `stdin` should contain `"15\n"`, `scanf` read and stores `15` in `x` and leaves the `'\n'` unread in `stdin`. Hard to see how that cause the issue.

Comment: seems to be a bug of clion itself: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/oauth?state=%2Fissue%2FCPP-2580

Comment: I tried this code with visual studio2017 c++14 and I haven't receive same response with you every thing works how its suppose to work with. So scanf doesn't print anything. Change your compiler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an issue in clion ([Why is CLion printing back inputs from standard input?](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000659630-Why-is-CLion-printing-back-inputs-from-standard-input-)). Currently unresolved. This problem exist for C and C++.
This bug resides for four years. I definitely advice you to change your compiler if you are not bound this for a particular reason.

Comment: Thanks, I changed my compiler and everything works now.